# OpenGL shadow map identical on all objects

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, lwjgl, shadow

(Assignment related question)

I'm attempting to implement shadow mapping, by following [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping), however, I am having a kinda strange problem - all of the objects in my scene are getting the same shadow applied to them, like this: [image: Shadow Bug] (The light is at -3, 5, -3 (Bottom Right))

What have I done wrong? I think it is going to be matrix related, but I have no idea how to fix it...

Creating the view matrix:

```
viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
Matrix4f.rotate(MathHelpers.degreesToRadians(verticalRotation), new Vector3f(1f, 0f, 0f), viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
Matrix4f.rotate(MathHelpers.degreesToRadians(horizontalRotation), new Vector3f(0f, 1f, 0f), viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
Matrix4f.translate(position, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
viewMatrix.store(cameraMatrix);
cameraMatrix.flip();
```

Sending the data to the GPU:

```
Mat4 proj2 = Matrices.perspective(90, 1, 3f, 20f);
Mat4 view2 = = MathHelpers.Matrix4fToMat4(lights.get(i).getViewMatrix());
Mat4 model2 = Mat4.MAT4_IDENTITY;
Mat4 mvp = MathHelpers.biasMVP(proj2, view2, model2);
FloatBuffer matBuffer = org.lwjgl.BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
MathHelpers.Mat4ToMatrix4f(mvp).store(matBuffer);
matBuffer.flip();
```

Depth shaders:
http://pastebin.com/SqFaBnSE
http://pastebin.com/t5t35XNM

Normal shaders:
http://pastebin.com/yQhqyAWc
http://pastebin.com/2C2sXByz

Comment: In your vertex shader, you have to adjust your shadow Coordinate with the model's transfomations between your shadowmap creation and your model display: example tex[7] is for shadowmap transforms, modelView is individual model transformation: ShadowCoord= (gl_TextureMatrix[7] * inverse(modelView) * gl_ModelViewMatrix) * gl_Vertex;

Comment: So if I'm understanding your comment right, I need to change line 41 of http://pastebin.com/2C2sXByz to: `vec4 newShadowCoord = lights[0].matrix * (inverse( viewMatrix * modelMatrix ) ) * pass_Position;` ?
Doing this ends up with shadows that move with the camera, but I've seen other questions with the same problem, so I'll check those.
Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Oh, I am a fool, it should be: vec4 newShadowCoord = lights[0].matrix * (inverse( modelMatrix ) ) * pass_Position;, of course. Still failing for me though, in different ways. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I review a bit my code, and I've confused you: modelView uniform hold model matrix for the whole scene, while I retrieve current modelMatrix with depreciate 'gl_Matrices'  and get the shadow map delta from the difference between them (sorry if I confused you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out, eventually. It was a simple logical error, by not using the proper position.

`public static void setLightUniforms(int program, Matrix4f mat) {
     Mat4 proj2 = Matrices.perspective(90, 1, 3f, 20f);
     Mat4 view2 = = MathHelpers.Matrix4fToMat4(lights.get(i).getViewMatrix());
     Mat4 model2 = Mat4.MAT4_IDENTITY;`

I was always using the identity matrix for the position, instead of the location of the model I was calculating for.

The code is now (Note the usage of the parameter):

`public static void setLightUniforms(int program, Matrix4f mat) {
     Matrix4f proj = MathHelpers.Mat4ToMatrix4f(Matrices.perspective(90, 1, 3f, 20f));
     Matrix4f view = lights.get(i).getViewMatrix();
     Matrix4f bias = MathHelpers.Mat4ToMatrix4f(MathHelpers.biasMatrix);
     Matrix4f MVP = Matrix4f.mul(proj, Matrix4f.mul(view, mat, null), null);
     Matrix4f.mul(bias, MVP, MVP);`

Answer (score 0):

When you sample the shadow map you should first transform the world position of the fragment (before you apply the camera transform and perspective matrix) to the

in the vertex shader this will be:

```
attribute vec3 pos;

uniform mat4 shadowTransform;//the MVP you used to create the shadowmap
uniform mat4 MVP;

varying vec4 shadowPos;//you can use the xy/w to sample the shadow map and compare against z/w

main(){
   gl_position = MVP*vec4(pos,1);
   shadowPos = shadowTransform*vec4(pos, 1);
}
```

Comment: I was doing this in my fragment shader, as I have an array of lights (Of which only 1 is in use at the moment), by passing in_Position as out_Position. Even if I move the transform to the vertex shader, I get the same result (As expected) (IE `pass_Position = lights[1].matrix * in_Position;` in vertex is the same as `vec4 newShadowCoord = lights[0].matrix * pass_Position;` in fragment)